# What does тока позже mean?

Tags: перевод

I was kidding with friends about them sending me something irrealistic. The written answer I got was:

> тока позже!))

with "))" being what I think are the Russian emoticons for *lol* (without eyes - just the smile). *позже* is after but in [lingvo](http://www.lingvo-online.ru/en/Translate/en-ru/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) I didn't find something really helpful in order to translate *тока*, which is presummably the genitive of *ток*.

What does тока позже mean?

Comment: Overusing of "))" is very common in Russia. There is even a joke about it: No smiles @ Serious conversation.

Comment: My interpretation of that phrase would be close to "yeah right".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Тока" is a (usually intentionally) incorrect spelling of "только", imitating its common pronunciation (similar to "чо" = "что"). "Тока позже" thus means "only later" or "just later". The unmatched parentheses are indeed emoticons (I don't think this form is specific to Russia though).

Comment: `))` is much more prevalent in Russian than elsewhere because to type `:` on Russian keyboard layout you have to use `Shift+6`, while on English (US) layout it's `Shift+;`, which is much easier to type with one hand. So many people don't bother and skip the `:` when typing in Russian. BTW, that's also why you sometimes see `Ж))` instead.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I've always wondered about that, thanks! Although I very much doubt anyone using an English keyboard would write a `:` with one hand!

Comment: I do it all the time :)

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky It's not clear what you mean by 'easier to type with one hand'. Both `Shift + ;` and `Shift + 6` require both hands for typing.

Comment: @uvv the ';' key is very close to the right shift, so you can easily type ':' with just the right hand. See e.g. [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg)

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky well, I know the layout. I was talking from ten-finger-typing method perspective, which I assume to be correct ;) If you use one, then Shift is always pressed with opposite hand then the typed character.

Comment: As for me (I'm russian), ';' in english layout is much closer to the 'most used keys area' than 6. I on't think it has to do something with one-handed typing (I can easily press both Shift+6 and Shift+; with one hand even on full-size pc keyboard).
Also, I think ')' is a bit different from ':)'. I'd type ':)' to mark a joke, and ')' to mark that if I was saying this irl, I'd smile, and more parenthesizes means wider smile.

Comment: But there are exceptions. I still right full emoticons, and my American penmate frequently skip it to  parenthesis-only. Granted, she uses her phone a lot, and the phones do not have full-featured hardware keyboards :-D

Answer (score 1):

тока = is translating as = just, (right now), for the record guys, I'm russian )) = middle type smile)

Answer (score 0):

`тока позже` could be like "but/only later"
e.g.
`да, тока позже`like `yes, but/only later`

examples of right form
http://www.linguee.com/english-russian/search?source=auto&query=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B5